# What is wrong with this code? I need it to enter my database and then allow me to login using the parameters

Tags: php, html, authentication

I don't understand what is wrong with this code, I followed an old tutorial and it might be a bit dated so I'm unsure what is wrong. All the names for the database are correct and the functions should be fine, I have looked at the code for a while and can't see what is wrong.

```
<?php
error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        $form ="<form action='./login.php' method='post'>
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Username:</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='user' /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td><input type='password' name='password' /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type='submit' name='loginbtn' value='Login'/></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </form>";

        if ($_POST['loginbtn']) {

            $user = $_POST['user'];
            if ($user) {

                if ($password) {

                    require("connect.php");
                    $password = md5(md5("fghxjks".$password."HGJDjbCKGC"));
                    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userlogins WHERE username='$user'");
                    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
                    if ($numrows == 1) {

                        $row = msql_fetch_assoc($query);
                        $dbuser = $row['username'];
                        $dbpass = $row['password'];

                        if ($password == $dbpass) {
                            $_SESSION['userid'] = $dbid;
                            $_SESSION['username'] = $dbuser;
                            echo "You have been logged in as <b>$dbuser</b>.";
                        }
                        else {
                            echo "The password you entered is not correct.";
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        echo "The username you entered was not found. $form";
                    }
                   mysql_close();
                }
                else {
                    echo "You must enter your password. $form";
                }
            }
            else {
                echo "You must enter your username. $form";
           }
        }
        else {
            echo $form;
        }
    ?>
</body>
```

Comment: whats the error? without telling us whats wrong we cant help you! what is it meant to do and what is it doing instead of what you expect? Might be helpful if you show your whole code

Comment: exactly, what is wrong ? ;) (what's the error?)

Comment: sorry, I want it to get the username and password from my data base so it can then log you in if, as long as it meets the correct information

Comment: I would suggest putting the session in the header as at the bottom of your page everything would have loaded befoe you login, therefore the code above wont have seen the session variable

Comment: The `$password` variable is not set.

Comment: Thanks, I added the $password vaiable and then this appeared

Comment: Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\Local\connect.php on line 2

Comment: along with a number of other warnings :/

Comment: Yes, mysql_ functions are deprecated, but that's another problem. To solve your current problem, you just need to add one line of code (see my answer).

Answer (score -1):

The `$password` variable is not set. You should add:

```
$password = $_POST['password'];
```

Before `if ($password)`

Also, `$user` comes from user input (`$_POST['user']`). Never put user input directly in a `mysql_query`, as it makes the query vulnerable to SQL injection. In this case, the attacker won't be able to do much, because `mysql_query` doesn't support multiple queries. But you should always use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) on user input:

```
$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM userlogins WHERE username=\''.mysql_real_escape_string($user).'\'');
```

Comment: Your partially right and wrong, he sets the variable using this: $password = md5(md5("fghxjks".$password."HGJDjbCKGC")); BUT he hasnt used the password from the post

Comment: @NoLiver92 The code you are referring to will never get called, precisely because `$password` is not set, and the `if ($password)` condition will never be true.